# Android - How to use ORMLite dbhelper for whole app lifecycle

Tags: android, database, helper, ormlite, android-context

I'd like to use ORMLite, but I don't like I have manage 1 database helper for each activity. Wouldn't be better to have one for whole app lifecycle? Until now I've used greendao and it has not this issue.

I wanted to implement it, however I can't find any suitable way to release db helper properly when destroying app (I can easily open it in Application's onCreate), because there is no Application's onDestroy() method.

Does anyone have some way to do it?

Comment: Is it too expensive to open/close in Application's onResume/onPause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ormlite` has [OrmLiteBaseActivity](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/android/apptools/OrmLiteBaseActivity.java) which can manage connection with activity cycle by itself. All your activities should extend this class and you don't need to care when to destroy the connection. You can call helper in many times, the connection is released in 
 `onDestroy()` method of each activity.

If your activity is not base android activity, for example, `SherlockActivity` or `ActionBarActivity`, you may consider to copy code from  OrmLiteBaseActivity and make your own base activity, then extend it.

That is what I did in many applications and I don't see any problems with that. Hope this can help!
P/s: you can even do the same thing for android service with [OrmLiteBaseService](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/android/apptools/OrmLiteBaseService.java)

Comment: Hi, I did as you say, but at runtime I have this exception:      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find OpenHelperClass because none of the generic parameters of class class com.thinple.smart.android.activity.Act_LoginRegister extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.  You should use getHelper(Context, Class) instead.

That's because I already have a super activity which extends ActionBarActivity. I copied code from OrmLiteBaseActivity into my super activity, removing generic types (I know which is my db helper class).

Comment: If I call OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context, SmartBaseActivity.class) it doesn't compile

Comment: I solved using a singleton accessed through static synchronized getInstance() as stated by Gray Watson (ORMLite founder) in an answer here on Stack

Comment: @LorenzoBarbagli well, there were various ways to access ormlite helper. Singleton is a good way but you have to manage when to release the database connection. So I suggest the better way to use ormlite helper but respect activity life cycle. In your case, the second parameter in `getHelper` method is wrong. Here is an example for you http://pastebin.com/mBHTc0rQ

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Singleton` pattern:

```
package com.example.stackoverflowsandbox;

public class MySingletonHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
    private static MySingletonHelper instance;

    public static MySingletonHelper getInstance() {
        if ( MySingletonHelper.instance == null ) {
            MySingletonHelper.instance = new MySingletonHelper();
        }

        return MySingletonHelper.instance;
    }

    private MySingletonHelper() {
        // code here...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate( SQLiteDatabase arg0, ConnectionSource arg1 ) {
        // code here...
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade( SQLiteDatabase arg0, ConnectionSource arg1, int arg2, int arg3 ) {
        // code here...
    }
}
```

See more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: Yea sure I get that one, what this question is about is that when destroying app you need to call MySingletonHelper.instance.releaseHelper(); and because you are not using actyvity's lifecycle to manage helpers lifecycle, you have no idea when to release it. Right?